# Use exoplayer in viewpager with firebase realtime database

Tags: android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, exoplayer, android-viewpager2

i want to make reels/shorts app like tiktok.
i want to load videos with exoplayer in the viewPager2 and the video urls from the firebase database , e.g. youtube shorts , instagram reels.
please, can anybody give me a the java/kotlin code for it , it would be a great help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.